# Let's make a map Topojson doesn't appear - no error msgs but nothing happens

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I want to use D3 to plot a map of Brazil (state boundaries) but I'm failing. The map is in Topojson format (it's [here](https://gist.github.com/thiagomarzagao/61264e6b5fb2b8c1f6b7)) and I'm following Mike Bostock's [tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/). I can replicate the tutorial results exactly when plotting the UK (map [here](https://gist.github.com/thiagomarzagao/f5e06793717f513b6ed3)), but when I try plotting Brazil nothing happens - and there are no error messages in the JavaScript console.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 55.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(1200 * 5)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

/*
PLOTTING THE UK WORKS
d3.json("uk.json", function(error, uk) {
  console.log(uk)
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits))
      .attr("d", path);
});
*/

/* PLOTTING BRAZIL DOESN'T WORK */
d3.json("br-states.json", function(error, uf) {
  console.log(uf)
  svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(uf, uf.objects.states))
      .attr("d", path);
});

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: 1. Use jsoneditoronline.org to check your data structue.

Comment: It's 'geometries' inside 'states' (type: GeometryCollection) inside 'objects'. Inside 'geometry', numbers 0-26 (Brazil has 27 states). Inside each number, 'arcs' and 'properties'. Inside each arc (type: Polygon), more numbers (I'm guessing one per county).

Comment: You can upload your file to jsoneditoronline and share with us :)

Comment: I just tried, but I got "Error: Failed to save document". Maybe because of the size (3.8MB). But I saved it as a gist: https://gist.github.com/thiagomarzagao/61264e6b5fb2b8c1f6b7 (click "Raw" to see the data).

Comment: It handles >8MB. Should work ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following must be changed to your needs.

```
 // England viewport
var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 55.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(1200 * 5)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

Currently zooming on the area of England :)

Something such :

```
// somewhere in South america
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()   // albers may fails for Brazil
    .center([-40, -30])          // country center
    .rotate([4.4, 0])               //???? Check the api and edit for Brazil
    .parallels([0, -60])          // ???
    .scale(400)                     // smaller num = smaller Earth
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);  // topojson data is initially centered aroun x:0,y:0. This put back into the viewbox
```

Comment: You mean the final version of the plot? Will do! But it's going to be an interactive plot and I still need to learn how to do it, so it should take a while. :-)